# Recharts: using custom x-axis ticks with a <Brush />

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts, brush, x-axis

I've been trying to create a chart with `recharts` in `react` and I keep on getting the same issue with custom x-axis ticks rendering when using the `<Brush />` component.

I have a chunk of data to display for 1 day: `[{ date: '9:30', value: 1 }, { date: '9:35', value: 2 }, ...]`

There are also x-axis ticks for every hour generated separately: `['9:00', '10:00', ...]`

If I don't use zoom with the brush it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VXDP.png) but when I'm trying to zoom-in to see a specific time range all ticks disappear but [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmR9O.png) .

I can get the brush to work without custom ticks but I really need to show only hours without any intermediate values like `9:45` on the x-axis. Would be very glad to hear any feedback.

React v17.0.2
Recharts v2.1.9
Chrome Version 103.0.5060.53 (Official Build) (x86_64)

This example in a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-area-chart-forked-4kojl9?file=/src/App.tsx